# use variable in link_to url name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, link-to

I got HAML:

```
%li = link_to raw(t("link.nearby")), country_path(@entry.country_url)
```

... which is supposed to get link.nearby from a language file:

```
link:
  nearby: "&laquo; View yoga places in %{country}"
```

... however, this doesn't work and outputs:

> « View yoga places in %{country} .

Of course what I want is to make it replace %{country} with its actual value.

**edit:**

There is a translation of the website, where %{country} is not on the last position of the statement, so just appending it doesn't work here ... I guess it should rather be a modification on the language file-part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%li = link_to raw(t("link.nearby", :country=>@country_name)), country_path(@entry.country_url)
```

Comment: What you mean by "%{country} is not on the last position of the statement" and by "appending"??

Comment: the whole expression you gave doesn't work for me. furthermore, what is the expression supposed to do? append the country name to the through "link.nearby" referenced string, right?

Comment: @thomas JohnZ is using I18n interpolation, which is exactly what you need.  See the documentation here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation

Comment: 'what is the expression supposed to do?' It is supposed to generate the link, with the `%{country}` substituted with the value of `@country_name`. `:country=>@country_name` mean _substitute the value of `%{country}` in `link.nearby` with the value of `@country_name`_. It is not supposed to _append_ it, it is supposed to _substitute_ (interpolate).

Comment: @JohnZ I adapted it to '%li = link_to raw(t("link.nearby", :country=>@entry.country)), country_path(@entry.country_url)' and now it's working ... thx